# Why so many –ing nouns (present participles) do not take the definite article “the”?

Tags: definite-article, gerunds

For example we do not say:

> I look forward to **the** seeing you, or in **the** doing so.

But sometimes we say:

> In **the** beginning, in **the** fighting, **the** ruling, etc.

As such, is there any different rule concerning the **–ing nouns** or they should follow the same rules as the common nouns do?

Comment: Are you sure _seeing_ and _doing_ are **nouns** in those first examples? I suspect most people will interpret them as **verbs**.

Comment: Right, what oerkelens said. Sometimes *-ing* forms are verb forms, sometimes they're nouns.  Look at their modification, complementation, and inflectional forms to see.

Comment: Note that [beginning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/beginning), [fighting](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fighting), and [ruling](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ruling_2) have their own noun definitions, probably not only in Macmillan Dictionary. -- Also note that *look forward to our meeting* or *look forward to the meeting* is surely possible. -- And this is also possible: *I'm looking forward to our seeing each other again.*

Comment: @oerkelens, I' m not sure but in the sentence: "Seeing is good, doing is bad.", seeing and doing are not subjects and subjects are not nouns?

Comment: In _seeing is good, doing is bad_, they are indeed nouns. But there are no articles needed, just as in _men are from Mars, women are from Venus_.

Comment: Thank you @oerkelens, actually this is what I'm asking if they follow the same patterns as the ordinary nouns.

Comment: Related: [“I'm used to him being away ” or “I'm used to his being away”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19041/3281), [Gerund or participle?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/47873/3281), [Which is the correct gerund clause? 'People's killing animals', or 'People killing animals … '?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37280/3281).

Comment: When they are truly used as nouns, they act like other nouns, indeed. But When they are used as verbs they are and behave differently.

Comment: @oerkelens, I upvoted your last comment for this is what I actually needed to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'seeing' is not a noun there. It's a verb. And due to 'look forward...' pattern, it takes the verb in the form of '-ing'.

> I look forward to *<del>see</del>* seeing you.

Does the question still stand?

Comment: Thank you! So, when they are nouns, they follow the same patterns as the ordinary nouns, right?-:)

Comment: Nouns have no pattern! They are the verbs! Stop thinking about 'look forward to', take some other example and it'll be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because it is shorter, because the article does not achieve much, and because without article the sense is as clear as with article.