# Articles before -ing nouns

Tags: articles, nouns

I wonder if there's any rule behind using articles, both definite and indefinite, before "-ing" nouns, i.e. drinking, killing, upbringing and so on.

I feel like most of them can go both ways; I wouldn't mind saying:

> 1. My friend says that his parents didn't manage to give him a proper upbringing.

But, on the other hand, I don't feel like there's anything off with:

> 2. Proper upbringing is key.

Another such case presents itself with the word "killing".

> 3. Killing may seem difficult at first, but soldiers claim you can get used to it.

But, in a Dropkick Murphys' song, they go with:

> 4. The killing and dying - it was all done in vain.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61175/why-so-many-ing-nouns-present-participles-do-not-take-the-definite-article-t)

Comment: The "Killing" in your example #3 seems to be a verb, not a noun. Consider: *"Killing [people] may seem difficult at first, …"* which has a direct object "people" for the verb "killing"; and *"Killing [of people] may seem difficult at first, …"* which uses a noun "killing", but that noun example seems to be ungrammatical.

Comment: Gerunds and infinitives can take objects, yet still function as nouns.  *-ing* words can be part of an verb phrase if preceded by a form of *to be*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*-ing* words as nouns follow the same rules in regard to articles as any other nouns.  Exception: If the *-ing* word has a subject (which becomes an object from the point of view of the rest of the sentence) though, don't use any article.

Here's some really contrived examples:

(Definite article, we mean a specific X we mentioned or saw before)

*The candy tasted good.*

*The hiking made me feel better*

*Him hiking with her made me feel better.*

---

(Indefinite article, we don't mean a specific X)

*Are you going to find a paper clip?*

*Are you going to pay for a tanning later?*

*Are you going to pay for him tanning later?*

*Are you going to give him money for him donating to the church later?*

---

(No article, noun used in a general sense.)

*Flowers make me sneeze all the time.*

*Arguing makes my head hurt.*

*Arguing with her makes my head hurt.*

*Him arguing with her makes my head hurt.*